# Gitolite push error

Tags: git, gitolite

I have problem with my git, when I push my changes, git sends me this error:

```
git FATAL: split conf set, gl-conf not present for "name of repository"
```

What Can I do? Or how can I caused this problem?
Thanks for your help.

Meph

Comment: Did you recently upgrate to gitolite 3 ?

Comment: No, I installed gitolite for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

How did you create the remote repository? If you manually create a *bare* clone of your repository and moved it to the repository folder of Gitolite there are a couple of things which need to be setup manually:

1. Change the owner to the Gitolite user, e.g. `chown -R git:users`
2. Change the permissions for folders and files, e.g. `chmod -R 755 myproject.git`
3. Check if there is `gl-conf` in the `project.git/` folder. If not copy one from another working Gitolite project. Normally it gets setup automatically when you use *gitolite-admin* to configure a new project. Here is what the file looks like.

```sh
# gl-conf
%one_repo = (
  'myproject' => {
    'meph' => [
      [
        4,
        'RW+',
        'refs/.*'
      ]
    ]
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the file `gl-conf` is missing. You can create it on your own (see answer by JDD) or more simple just run the following command – gitolite will take care of the rest:

```
gitolite setup
```

The problem can be caused if you migrate a bare repository to gitolite. A `gl-conf` file is needed by gitolite to store the “compiled” configuration only for the specific repository. The data is taken from `gitolite-admin/conf/gitolite.conf` (the repository, where you put the access configuration to the repositories in).

Answer (score 1):

That error message comes from [`src/lib/Gitolite/Conf/Load.pm`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Conf/Load.pm#L235-L264):

```
 if ( -f "gl-conf" ) {
    return if not $split_conf{$repo};

    my $cc = "./gl-conf";
    _die "parse '$cc' failed: " . ( $! or $@ ) unless do $cc;

    $last_repo = $repo;
    $repos{$repo} = $one_repo{$repo};
    $configs{$repo} = $one_config{$repo} if $one_config{$repo};
} else {
    _die "split conf set, gl-conf not present for '$repo'" if $split_conf{$repo};
}
```

So it it expected a local gitolite config in your bare repo, as if it were a ["big-config"](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/g2/bc.html) from gitolite g2.
Check if you still have a `$GL_BIG_CONFIG = 1;` in the `~/.gitolite.rc`, while being now in gitolite g3.

Comment: Hi,in gitolite.rc I had not $GL_BIG_CONFIG, so I added it, but nothing to happened.

Comment: @Meph- are you using gitolite v2 or v3?

Comment: @Meph- then following http://serverfault.com/a/422449/783, a complete re-installation of gitolite could help.